# Passing mysql result $row to another method in a class

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I Have a Main class Employee which fetches Employees Details,Passed Inputs it fetches mysql results and RETURNS into a associate array into $row.

```
  public function Result(){
    $this->IsEmptyCheck();
    $this->ConnectDb();
    $this->QueryDb();
    $this->RowCount();  

    $this->IfEmployeeFound();
    }

 public function IfEmployeeFound(){

    if ($this->row_cnt > 0)
    {

              while ($row = $this->result->fetch_assoc()){

            return($row);
            }

    }else{echo "No Results" ;}

}

public function CustomhtmlTabledisplay($row){

      foreach ( $row as $key => $value ) { 

            echo .....
            echo "<td>".$value['employee_name']."</td>\n"; 
            echo "<td>".$value['age']."</td>\n"; 
            echo "<td>".$value['familydetails']."</td>\n"; 
            echo ..... 

          }
}
```

I am running the below php call calling the employee class and executing above functions in it like this.

```
$check = new Employee($employeeid);

$check->Result()->CustomhtmlTabledisplay();

$check->CloseDb();
```

### How can i achieve it ?

1. I would like to fetch the data by passing the mysql returned rows array from
   **IfEmployeeFound()** into **CustomhtmlTabledisplay();**
2. I would like to display employee details by executing this type of query
   **$check->Result()->CustomhtmlTabledisplay();**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(If I understood). For doing next - `by executing this type of query`:

```
$check->Result()->CustomhtmlTabledisplay();
```

You need `return $this` in end of every method for chaining methods. And store need data in `property`-fields of your Main Class.

**EDIT**

If you want use your class like this

```
$check->CustomhtmlTabledisplay(($check->Result());
```

change class methods  to:

```
  public function Result(){
    $this->IsEmptyCheck();
    $this->ConnectDb();
    $this->QueryDb();
    $this->RowCount();  

    return $this->IfEmployeeFound();
  }

  public function IfEmployeeFound(){

    $out = array();
    if ($this->row_cnt > 0){
     while ($row = $this->result->fetch_assoc())
        $out[] = $row;
    }

     return empty($out)? null: $out;    
   }

   public function CustomhtmlTabledisplay($rows){

     if($rows){
       foreach ( $rows as $row) { 

         echo .....
         echo "<td>".$row['employee_name']."</td>\n"; 
         echo "<td>".$row['age']."</td>\n"; 
         echo "<td>".$row['familydetails']."</td>\n"; 
         echo ..... 

       }
    }

   }
```

Comment: I Tried this $check->CustomhtmlTabledisplay(($check->Result()); This works to an extent but faces an issue with foreach ($row as ....)

Comment: @BetaCoder if you want like this `$check->CustomhtmlTabledisplay(($check->Result());`,change end of  method `Result` to `return  $this->IfEmployeeFound();`

Comment: There is no Need of changing as IfEmployeeFound() returns a $row ,i have succeded in passing the fetched rows to CustomhtmlTabledisplay, The problem now is executing the foreach ( $row as $k => $v) ..getting error at foreach instruction.

Comment: @BetaCoder some minutes.. i change answer

Comment: Its an associated array so having some issues with foreach end

Comment: @BetaCoder what issues?

Comment: @BetaCoder what issues? sorry, doesn`t use `$key => $value`. I changed answer.

Comment: Excellent the Approach really worked, return $this->IfEmployeeFound(); and foreach Tweaking Worked, Thanks a Ton  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
require_once (employee.php); //employee is the file where you have the methods
```

And instance the class employee

Comment: All the class(inside methods) and php execution is in the same file,No need of anything required further, The Objective is to pass results fetched from db query into another method !